# Why does Adapter Always sends the Last Item data to Another Activity?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

> This is my Adapter class `onBindViewHolder` method :

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {


    final DetailModel detailModel = detailModelList.get(position);
    currPos = detailModel.getClick();
    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(mCtx);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(mCtx.getResources().getString(R.string.admob_inter_ads));
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
    holder.homeCards.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                mInterstitialAd.show();
            } else {
                Intent intent = new Intent(mCtx, WebViewActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("Web", String.valueOf(currPos));
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                mCtx.startActivity(intent);

            }


        }
    });

    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            // Load the next interstitial.

            Intent intent = new Intent(mCtx, WebViewActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("Web", String.valueOf(detailModel.getClick()));
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            mCtx.startActivity(intent);
            mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
        }

    });
```

> But, everytime the Intent is sending Data to Another Activity which is `WebViewActivity` in this case, then the Last Item in the List is always send and not the Current data !  **(its always the case, when the Ad is closed)**

> This is the code that is sending data to WebviewActivity as you can also see in the code :

```
 intent.putExtra("Web", String.valueOf(detailModel.getClick()));
```

> the `detailModel.getClick()` is just the Link which I'm receiving from a database.

> How to fix this Issue, so that the current item data is send and not the last one. Pls Guide

Comment: what is `detailModel.getClick();`

Comment: its just the link that is received from Database

Comment: Im having the Same Issue, The last item is always send and not the current positions item. Dunno why !

Comment: @Sainita have you tried printing currPos value? is it coming correct?

Comment: Yes, i printed in Logcat, its receiving the Value, but always the Last item in the List. No matter, which cardView i click

Answer (score -1):

Since always `onBindViewHolder` will be called for all the positions on screen and since it will not be called for the position you click, the last item is being passed to `WebViewActivity`.

Try the following way:

```
holder.homeCards.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                mInterstitialAd.show();
            } else {
                Intent intent = new Intent(mCtx, WebViewActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("Web", detailModelList.get(getAdapterPosition).getClick());
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                mCtx.startActivity(intent);

            }


        }
    });

    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            // Load the next interstitial.

            Intent intent = new Intent(mCtx, WebViewActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("Web", String.valueOf(detailModelList.get(getAdapterPosition).getClick()));
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            mCtx.startActivity(intent);
            mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
        }

    });
```

Comment: Sorry, your Answer just sends the current Adapter position to another Activity. But, if you see in the code above, its sending an actual data from a list and not the current position

Comment: @Sainita as I see you are sending just link `detailModel.getClick()`. Can you tell me where you are sending actual data?

Comment: @Sainita I have updated the answer, pls check that